# DynamoDB Fine-Grained Access Control and secondary indexes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

So, I am currently making a DynamoDB table with multiple indexes and trying to manage access control.

I have a key (organizationId) that I do not want to use as my secondary indexes partition or sort key, because it would be pretty much pointless query-wise.

**DynamoDB table**

- Table name: Executions
- Partition key: OrganizationId (String)

**DynamoDB Secondary Index**

- Primary partition key: processId (String)
- Primary sort key: status (Number)

Would the following IAM Policy condition effectively limit access on the secondary index based on the organizationId ?

```
"Condition": {
    "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
        "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": [
            "anOrganizationId / Variable"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: No; I've pretty much given up

Comment: i think i solved it, added a comment if you'd like to try

Answer (score -1):

Ok, what i can suggest - you could actually do the 2nd index as "OrganizationId#processId" - the organization ID should be always known when searching - as you plan i guess to search of all items within an organization with specific process ID?

This should work out for you (on the index, not the table)

```
"Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringLike": {
                    "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": "${aws:PrincipalTag/organizationId}#*"
                },
```

if i'm assuming the tag is with the org id

Comment: This is a novel approach, but are you sure that it actually works? According this page Dynamodb does not support 'Authorization based on Tags' https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_aws-services-that-work-with-iam.html

Comment: I'm using it on my environment, and it works for me. If it doesn't for you, I'll recheck the configuration, did you try it?

Comment: I did tried this, but wasn't able to get it working. Interested to hear if you are able to confirm your configuration.

Comment: Ah, i'm using this configuration not for indexes, but for the entire table - this is inherited from the table, are you able to make it work first without indexes?

Answer (score -2):

following permissions policy allows queries on a secondary index (here example index name: TopScoreDateTimeIndex) by using the dynamodb:Attributes condition key. The policy also limits queries to requesting only specific attributes that have been projected into the index.
Please pay attention at Resource and Condition section

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "QueryOnlyProjectedIndexAttributes",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:Query"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:123456789012:table/GameScores/index/TopScoreDateTimeIndex"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                    "dynamodb:Attributes": [
                        "TopScoreDateTime",
                        "GameTitle",
                        "Wins",
                        "Losses",
                        "Attempts"
                    ]
                },
                "StringEquals": {
                    "dynamodb:Select": "SPECIFIC_ATTRIBUTES"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This limits the attributes that can be retrieved, but it doesn't limit which rows can be retrieved